# Photostream example: photos sized for larger screens

Tags: android, screen

I'm using the [Photostream example](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/#git/Photostream) app to learn Android.

One thing I've noticed is that on my 800x480 4.0 phone the 6 photos in the grid fill the screen. However, on the 1024x768 pixel display of my 2.3 running touchpad they do not fill the screen, and are instead constrained to a tight grid towards the top-centre of the screen.

I want to adjust the app so it sizes itself appropriate to the screen size but I can't figure out why it's sizing the way it is.

Looking at the layouts in the res/ directory most of them specify fill_parent etc. The only explicit sizing I can see is the 150x128dip in grid_item_photo, but if I double this it seems to make no difference.

I tried changing the code in PhotostreamActivity.java to download SMALL instead of THUMBNAIL sized photos and it indeed seems to do that. However, it doesn't change the overall layout or sizing as they are cropped. This happens even with the above change.

I notice some sizing code in GridLayout.onMeasure() but this all seems to be driven by the existing size of the screen/widgets -- I don't see it enforcing an arbitrarily small size.

Another thing which occurred to me was that maybe it's to do with the resolution, but I don't see any hvga specific layouts or values in the res directory, just some overrides for landscape vs. portrait.

Why is the current code sizing things the way it does, and what is the best way to modify this so it works on physically larger, perhaps lower density screens?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add this to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" />
```

Apparently, it is not default on for all devices, unlike the other similar settings.